# cURL not sure if enabled

Tags: php, curl

I am just not sure if the cURL library is enable in my php server.

when i run phpinfo() on server i got in configure command " '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' " but in cURL part it says "cURL support enabled cURL Information libcurl/7.12.1 OpenSSL/0.9.7a zlib/1.2.1.2 libidn/0.5.6"

is the cURL enabled or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do:

```
<?php
var_dump(curl_version());
?>
```

if it doesn’t exist you’ll see an error message like this:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function: curl_version()**

Answer (score 2):

```
$has_cURL = function_exists("curl_init");
```

That'd tell you right away whether cURL is enabled or not.